# Best practices for documenting ASP.NET code

Tags: asp.net, documentation-generation

Any preferences for Asp.Net programmers on how to document their code?

I read XML with Sandcastle is a good way to go. What do you use?

Comment: What does StyleCop tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML + GhostDoc + Sandcastle works well when you are developing an API that will need documentation and/or want intellisense support. These will be useful to you and anyone else who uses what you've built, even if they aren't looking at your source code. This also allows you to create links among documents.

Inline comments are only useful to you or others who are looking through your source code. They have a place, and don't necessarily need to be abandoned, but most inline comments can be obviated by favouring a declarative coding style over an imperative style and using descriptive, meaningful variable and member names. These can go a long way toward creating self-documenting code.

Comment: I installed Sandcastle but cannot see where it is in VS.  Is there a GUI?

Comment: @Tea You probably also want the builder: http://shfb.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Such documentation will:

1. Get stale.
2. Become prohibitively expensive to maintain over time.

While understanding that the two are not mutually exclusive...

> Favor [self-documenting code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting) over external documentation.